# Finding coordinate in a quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, quadrilateral

Im trying to do a simulation using Matlab to solve some fluid problem.
For this problem I have the following shape:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Okp8K.png)

For each black point I know the (x,y) coordinates.

I need to find the coordinates of the blue points which are located at 75% of the x coordinate between each two black dots and at the middle between the y coordinate of each two black dots.

I have been trying for a while but cant find simple method.

If someone can help with the logic/some code it will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm guessing your description of where the blue point are is unclear, because you already described it with a formula, and you can directly use that formula (i.e. add up the y-coordiantes and divide by 2).

Comment: I know where the blue point should be, however when thinking about the problem as problem with above 1000 points I cant figure out the iterative formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use standard isoparametric representation. For example, use the formula from slides 21 and 22 from http://www.rpi.edu/~des/Isoparametric.ppt

In your case for $(x_{i},y_{i})$, start with co-ordinate for top left corner for $(x_{1}, y_{1})$ and go counter-clockwise for the next three. Use $s=0.5$ and $t=0$ in the formulas below.

$$
x = \sum_{i} N_{i}(s,t) x_{i}
$$
$$
y = \sum_{i} N_{i}(s,t) y_{i}
$$
$$
\begin{matrix}
N_{1}(s,t) & = & (1-s)(1-t)/4 \\ 
N_{2}(s,t) & = & (1+s)(1-t)/4 \\ 
N_{3}(s,t) & = & (1+s)(1+t)/4 \\ 
N_{4}(s,t) & = & (1-s)(1+t)/4 
\end{matrix}
$$

Comment: I would type the equations. You never know when the link becomes invalid

Comment: It works thank you very much. Can you please just explain what the s and t means?

Comment: The quadrilateral is mapped into a square with co-ordinates $(-1,-1), (1,-1), (1,1), (-1,1)$. $s$ and $t$ are the co-ordinates in this square. For mid-point in $y$, $t=0$. For $3/4$ point in $x$, $s=0.5$. You can download the power point for more details. This mapping technique is used in finite element analysis.

Comment: Thats an awesome answer, that you very much